# glColorPointer performance, better with floats or bytes?

Tags: opengl

Doing some maintenance on an old project and was asked by the client to see if it was possible to improve performance. I've done the parts I know and can easily test but then I tested

glColorPointer(4,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,...,...)
vs
glColorPointer(4,GL_FLOAT,...,...)

I could see literally no difference on the handful of machines I could test it on. Obviously it means thats not a bottleneck but since it's the first time I've been in a situation where I have access to both color formats it's also the first time I can wonder if there's a speed difference between the 2.

I'm expecting the answer is internally opengl adapters use float colors so it would be preferable to use float when available but anyone have a more definitive answer then that?

edit: the client has a few dozen machines that are ~10 year old and the project is used on those machines if it makes a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no generally valid answer. You did the right thing by testing.

At least on desktop GPUs, it's fairly safe to assume that they will internally operate with 32-bit floats. On mobile GPUs, lower precision formats are more common, and you have some control over it using `precision` qualifiers in the shader code.

Assuming that 32-bit floats are used internally, there are two competing considerations:

1. If you specify the colors in a different format, like `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, a conversion is needed while fetching the vertex data.
2. If you specify the colors in a more compact format, the vertex data uses less memory. This also has the effect that less memory bandwidth is consumed for fetching the data, with fewer cache misses, and potentially less cache pollution.

Which of these is more relevant really depends on the exact hardware, and the overall workload. The format conversion for item 1 can potentially be almost free if the hardware supports the byte format as part of fixed function vertex fetching hardware. Otherwise, it can add a little overhead.

Saving memory bandwidth is always a good thing. So by default, I would think that using the most compact representation is more likely to be beneficial. But testing and measuring is the only conclusive way to decide.

In reality, it's fairly rare that fetching vertex data is a major bottleneck in the pipeline. It does happen, but it's just not very common. So it's not surprising that you couldn't measure a difference.

For example, in a lot of use cases, texture data is overall much bigger than vertex data. If that is the case, the bandwidth consumed by texture sampling is often much more significant than the one used by vertex fetching. Also, related to this, there are mostly many more fragments than vertices, so anything related to fragment processing is much more performance critical than vertex processing.

On top of this, many applications make too many OpenGL API calls, or use the API in inefficient ways, and end up being limited by CPU overhead, particularly on very high performance GPUs. If you're optimizing performance for an existing app, that is pretty much the first thing you should check: Find out if you're CPU or GPU limited.